# Styling a CSS Button with Pointed Left Edge and Rounded Right Edge

Tags: css, css-selectors

Updated again with Safari screenshot after @LGSon's answer:

[image]

**Update:**

Thanks for your answers, but the following code does not produce the correct effet, one can clearly see the separation between the SVG and the `a` tag because of the difference in height:

```css
.divsclass {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 146 206'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.c1%7Bfill:%23fff;%7D.c2%7Bfill:none;stroke:%23a0310f;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;%7D%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpath d='M146 0H98.53l-1 .47-94 94a12 12 0 0 0 0 17l94 94L99 206h47z' class='c1'/%3E%3Cpath d='M113.18 28.2l-73 74.8 73 74.81' class='c2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.divsclass a {
  color: red;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: .75em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 1em; background: black">
  <div class="divsclass"><a role="button">BACK</a></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create the following button where the text inside it (BACK in the example below) can be of variable length. I'm trying with a background image on the left and a border radius on the right but it's not working (using `:before`). Any ideas?

P.S. I do have an image of the left triangle as a separate SVG if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your CSS code, please?

Comment: If you have the left triangle as an SVG, why not just make the entire button shape an SVG (or at least, the left part of it, the rest of it could be a normal div with rounded corners on the right side so it can stretch easily due to the content)? Otherwise, trying to generate that rounded point on the left with CSS will require something like clip-path ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path ) or other weird hacks. SVG is perfect for this

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the issue, even while using SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using CSS alone in combination with the pseudo elements

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a::before,
a::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
  z-index: -1;
}
a::after {
  left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">BACK</a>
```

---

Updated

And here is a version using the existing SVG and a pseudo

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 20px;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 75%;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -14px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 146 206'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E.c1%7Bfill:%23fff;%7D.c2%7Bfill:none;stroke:%23a0310f;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:10px;%7D%3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpath d='M146 0H98.53l-1 .47-94 94a12 12 0 0 0 0 17l94 94L99 206h47z' class='c1'/%3E%3Cpath d='M113.18 28.2l-73 74.8 73 74.81' class='c2'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<span><a role="button">BACK</a></span>
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks perfect! Instead of `div`, can I also use `a` or would that not work?

Comment: @Sammy Updated my answer using an anchor instead

Comment: Thank you... so that's working well, except on Safari!

Comment: @Sammy How does it look on Safari? .. Screen shoot?

Comment: I pasted it in my question (I updated the CSS colors to white and red instead of lightgray and black, just in case you wonder!

Comment: On another note, the reason why I pasted my SVG is because, if you notice, the left arrow does not actually extend to the edge of the button.

Comment: @Sammy Updated with a second sample...will have a look later on the first, to see how to best fix so it looks the same

Comment: @Sammy Can you give me the code you used from my first sample, that didn't work on Safari...as a fiddle would be great

Comment: It's actually your exact same code, just the colors changing. (Trying the SVG version...)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a div as a button and an image as a background you can make your CSS like this:

```
div.divsclass {
 border-radius: 15px 50px 30px 5px:
}
```

So you can set the border-radius in all of the 4 corners, if you want to only with CSS. Or edit your SVG, as mentioned before.

Comment: The problem (as you can see if you run the code above) is that this depends upon the size of the font and is displayed at different heights on each browser. I'm unable to align the pixels of the `a` tag and the background.